# Android activity like whats app default activity

Tags: android

I have an activty that contains listview and on the bottom there is edittext andbottom aligned 
similar to whatsapp default activty 
when I click on the edittext on the bottom the soft keyboard pushes the bottom and the edit text up but it doest do the same for the list view so the bottom part of the list view disapear under the botton and the text view

here is my XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.testsms.app.SMSList">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contactList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        >
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </Button>

        <EditText

            android:id="@+id/EditText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your AndroidManifest.xml and add/modify your activity's android:windowSoftInputMode attribute. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft for a list of what each option can do. Sounds like you might want to try `adjustPan`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push edittext up with keyboard, you have to set RelativeLayout instead of main RinearLayout. so LinearLayout included with edittext and button will be located in bottom of activity. and when you click the edittext, the keyboard will be push up with it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

...<ListView>    

<EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
android:textStyle="normal"
>
</EditText> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: edittext already pushed up with the botton but the problem with the list view it'snt  pushed up

Comment: No not yet still trying several things